# Request method 'PUT' not supported StatusCode: 405

Tags: java, c#, rest, put

I get this warning

```
2017-05-25 00:48:43.125  WARN 7104 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'PUT' not supported
```

in intelliJ when I'm trying to do an update from c# (Visual Studio). But when I'm doing that update from Java, it works.

update method in Java:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Proba update(@RequestBody Proba proba) {
    System.out.println("Updating proba ...");
    try{
        probaRepository.update(proba.getIdProba(),proba);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return proba;
}
```

C# method

```
static async Task<string> UpdateProbaAsync(string path, Proba proba)
    {
        string res = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(path, proba);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

and here is how I call UpdateProbaAsync

```
        var rezU = await UpdateProbaAsync("http://localhost:8080/concurs/probe", new Proba(9, "cautare comori UPDATE", "3-5 ani", 0));
        var probeUpdate = await GetProbaAsync("http://localhost:8080/concurs/probe");
        foreach (var proba in probeUpdate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(proba.ToString());
        }
```

this is what I get for HttpResponseMessage response

```
 +      response    {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: close
  Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 21:57:39 GMT
  Allow: POST
  Allow: GET
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
```

Comment: I'm confused about your request URL of `/concurs/probe` vs the mapping of `/{id}`, especially given that you don't even use path variable `id` for anything. Is there also a `@RequestMapping` annotation on the class?

Comment: Yes, @Andreas `@RestController
@RequestMapping("/concurs/probe")`

Comment: Combining the two, you get `/concurs/probe/{id}`, but your request is just `/concurs/probe`, so that's not a match.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the attribute from the c#

```
    [HttpPut]   //or [HttpPost]
    [Route("/{path}")]
 async Task<string> UpdateProbaAsync(string path, Proba proba)
  {
  }
```

default is GET and you are trying to put onto a GET API